# Using XDebug and PhpStorm from guest VM, via host browser

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, phpstorm, x11, xdebug

I have a bit of a peculiar setup: On a Windows 10 host, I have an Ubuntu VirtualBox guest running. I use an SSH terminal with X11 forwarding to launch PhpStorm directly from the guest and display it on my host. My web server is also on the VM, and I access it from my host machine's browsers with a virtual host such as, say, `http://local.dev`.

This setup works rather nicely, allowing me to skip copying my server files to the host to edit them with a host-based PhpStorm. However, I have difficulties properly getting XDebug to run on the host machine's browser.

The only way I've managed to debug things is by adding `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START` at the end of URLs I launch from my host browser, however this only works for breakpoints in immediately executed code, rather than AJAX calls, as I get the following PhpStorm message after the page is loaded:

> 16:53:02 Debug session was finished without being paused
>            It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.

How to set up XDebug on the VM to allow debugging from the host browser? I've tried mapping paths, however it seems to make no sense, as for PhpStorm and XDebug the files *aren't* on a remote host.

Comment: The message you quoted tells that XDebug is properly configured on the server and can communicate with PhpStorm. Check "Break at first line in PHP scripts" (in the "Run" menu) and try again. The script should stop in the debugger on its first line and PhpStorm will ask you to define the paths mapping.